# Fill USPS webform dropdown using VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, webforms

I am trying to automatically fill a USPS webform, and it is working for street address, city and zipcode, but I can't make it fill the State dropdown. Any ideas?

Here's the code I currently have:

```
Sub USPS()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction!input.action?mode=1&refresh=true"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4

Call IE.Document.getElementByID("tAddress").SetAttribute("value", "2 Peabody Terrace")
Call IE.Document.getElementByID("tCity").SetAttribute("value", "Cambridge")
Call IE.Document.getElementByID("sState").SetAttribute("value", "MA")
Call IE.Document.getElementByID("Zzip").SetAttribute("value", "02138")

Set AllHyperLinks = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
    If ID = "lookupZipFindBtn" Then
        hyper_link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change to your code:

```
'Call IE.Document.getElementByID("sState").SetAttribute("value", "MA")
With IE.Document.getElementByID("sState")
    For i = 0 To .Length - 1
        If .Item(i).Value = "MA" Then
            .Item(i).Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
```

This will work... but the web page will still show like the Select element has not changed. It's an illusion. I suspect there is some JavaScript in the page interfering with this element's display.

HOWEVER, if you do this in the Immediate Window of the VBEditor:

```
?IE.Document.getElementByID("sState").value
```

...you will see that the value for the control has indeed changed to 'MA'.

Further, if you go ahead and click on the web page's Find button, you will see that 'MA' was in fact included under 'You entered:'.

So my code above is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working, but not because the State is changed but because the website doesn't require the State (even if it says it does). So when I click find, it throws the address without the state, and using the Zipcode to find the correct location.

Comment: That' great. But are you saying the above code did not result in `MA` making it to the server? It certainly does work here. Again, it does not change the appearance of the form, but it does change the actual value of the control... which gets passed to the server.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I rechecked it and it is working!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selectors:**

You can use css selectors to do this.

① The first selector I use is for the initial landing page to select the `search by address`:

```
#zip-lookup-app a > span
```

This says `span` tag within an `a` tag, inside element with id `zip-lookup-app`. `"#"` means id.

This matches the following, of which I want the first.

[image: CSS query]

② The second selector:

```
#tState option[value='MA']
```

This says select `option` tag with attribute `value`, having value of `'MA'`, within element with id `tState`. The `"[]"` means attribute.

---

**VBA:**

As I want the first match I can use the `querySelector` method of `document` to apply the CSS selector as shown below:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeStateSelection()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction!input.action?mode=1&refresh=true"

        While .Busy Or .READYSTATE < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document
        html.querySelector("#zip-lookup-app > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span").Click

        While .Busy Or .READYSTATE < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        html.querySelector("#tState option[value='MA']").Selected = True

       'other code
        Stop '<== Delete me

        '.Quit '<== Uncomment me
    End With
End Sub
```